# Repo specific ignore files in git

Tags: git, gitignore

Is it possible to have repo specific .gitignore files? Eg:

[origin]
.gitignore:

- foo1.*
- foo2.*

[another] .gitignore:

- bar1.*
- bar2.*

The purpose behind this is that we deploy using git on to a managed cloud service and we'd like to keep dev files in version control but not push them to a repo.

Comment: The ignore mechanism doesn't affect files that are already tracked in git.  That means that even if you use `.git/info/exclude` in `another` to ignore the developer files, if you deploy a commit to there which contains files that the ignore rules match, they will still be checked out.  You can get around this by pushing a release branch which doesn't have those files committed, or change your deploy mechanism to get around this.

Comment: Do you track the `.gitignore` file itself in the repository?

Comment: I think that's gonna be the case: create a bash script that merges the latest working copy into a deploy branch, cleans it up, tags it and then deploys its ass

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can put per repository ignore patterns in `.git/info/exclude` in each repository.

(Note, this only affects what is ignored in each repository, it won't affect files that you actively place under source control and the push. I'm not completely clear on your desired use case.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just can't have them in the same folder. If you create a new folder, day "deploy" and publish your deploy data there, it will use the .gitignore in that folder (not the root one).

Comment: I don't think a folder will be an elegant solution but your idea has inspired me to look at using a deploy branch

Comment: A deploy branch is a good idea. We actually create two repositories for when we deploy code, a "code" repo and a "deploy" repo. We publish our deploy code to the deploy repo and branch for every version, this way we have each deployed version easily accessible. We've even put git on the server and done checkouts to branches to push code.

Answer (score 0):

**My Situation：**

> Having a file named `alex.todo` which contains my personal notes about the project. I have two remote repo to push(`origin` and `alex`). One for sharing the code with other developers(I use `.gitignore` to exclude the `alex.todo` file), one just for backing up this project which is ok to preserve the `alex.todo` file.

**My final solution:**

> Using a temp branch to push the `alex.todo` to the backup repo.

```sh
# Step 1
git checkout -b alex # 'alex' or whatever branch name you prefer

# Step 2
# now you can edit your .gitignore to include your 'alex.todo' file

# Step 3
git add . && git commit -m 'commit some ignore files'
git push alex alex:master # git push <remote> <local branch name>:<remote branch to push into>

# Step 4
git checkout master  # return to branch master and do any editings(commits)

# Step 5
# make sure branch alex is in sync with master whenever you want to push the project to the backup repo
git checkout alex
git merge master # .gitignore will not automatically be included for commit unless specifically added
# now you can repeat step 3 to push the project to the backup repo
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably do this using git hooks (the scripts in .git). post-checkout sounds good.