# Exclude a subfolder only for Github with .gitignore

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a project which is pushed to both of Github and Bitbucket repos:

```
git push github master
git push bitbucket master
```

Github is public, Bitbucket is private repo.

My problem is I use this repo to develop a side project inside which later will be a completely standalone one, but right now I'm using heavily this project's resources, so that's why I started the new project's rough code here. I want to hide this new project's code in this repo only from Github, because that's a public. Is it possible within `.gitignore` with some Github specific prefixes?

If it's not possible, than I start a new repo for the new project, but right now it's saves lots of common code for the new one.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965431/repo-specific-ignore-files-in-git

Comment: Sorry, but Git manages the entire tree.  What you're asking for is to essentially version the directory for one hosting provider and not the other, and Git just doesn't do that. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your side project inside which later will be a completely standalone one, you should reference your super project as a dependency.

This means go ahead and create the new repository and push it to private remote. Then you've got at least 3 ways to include your public library:

1. Use a dependency manager like npm, composer, gem, or whatever is best for your language.
2. [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)
3. [subtrees](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)